# Configurable Product Help

Tags: configurable-product, products, magento2.1.0

I'm new to Magento (using v2.1.0) and I own a videogame store in Reno, Nevada.

I love how M2 looks, the multitude of extensions and the great forums for support.  I have a question which I'm hoping someone here can help me with...

Let's say I have a product, "SUPER MARIO BROS. 3" for the Nintendo.  For each of my videogame products, I can have up to 4 different choices.  They are: NEW, COMPLETE, BOXED, GAMEONLY.  What I'd like to do is have each game show up on the website to customers with the title and a dropdown box to choose which variation they want to purchase and price per each.

Example:

SUPER MARIO BROS 3

(These are the drop down options.)

-> NEW ($199.99)

-> COMPLETE ($24.99)

-> BOXED ($22.99)

-> GAMEONLY ($19.99)

So when the customer chooses to buy the game, she clicks on the dropdown box to choose which variation and price the customer would like to pay.  Assuming all 4 are in-stock, she could choose the variation and price.

I've imported a listing for each individual game for each system, set up all the categories and now I'm stuck.  I have in inventory 1 of each (all named GAMEONLY).

I see Attribute Sets and all the examples I see out there are T-Shirts and colors.  I'm pretty much a newb to Magento (have been using Zen Cart for 5 years).

Can someone point me in the right direction (about to watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMP-eUOdrs4 so that might explain things well enough)?

I've searched the forums for some help but jeeze... there's so many questions I couldn't find one that was like mine (though 100s of pages there probably is).

Thanks in advance for any help.  In the Zen Cart forums, I always had an answer back within a day.  I think Magento is more popular and useful... though this is my first question :) -Jake

Comment: Best place to start is by reading the [Magento User Guide](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/getting-started.html). It's thorough and will take some time to read and understand everything, but don't sell yourself short by just skimming it. It sounds like this video game store is your livelihood so invest the time in yourself sooner than later. Magento also offers courses through [Magento U](https://magento.com/training/catalog/magento-2).  They can be pricey but nothing beats investing in yourself and I would argue no one knows Magento 2 better than Magento.

Answer (score 0):

That video shows you almost the whole process.

1. You will need to use an attribute.
   If all your products are different, just hit create new attribute, and assign mario_package
2. Sku's and attributes
   Your configurable product is MARIO_ROOT, and the options are the simple products you have already imported.

Each simple product needs to have an attribute MARIO_PACKAGE set, so you can create the configurations. they are these:
-> NEW

-> COMPLETE

-> BOXED

-> GAMEONLY

3. Creating the configurations:
   On MARIO_ROOT, create the configuration based on MARIO_PACKAGE
   Once you get to this screen in the video, choose the select on the right of each product and click assign product manually.
   That will override the default system sku_root + attribute by your single product sku.

[image]

Remember the simple products must have the attribute set.